# VB.Net multiple process with checkbox

Tags: vb.net

I want to know the code to the following illustration.
i have one form with some checkboxs and one button, 
[screen is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9knC.jpg)
i've try with this code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      If CheckBox1.Checked = True And CheckBox2.Checked = True And CheckBox3.Checked = True And CheckBox4.Checked = True Then  
          'when the button is clicked will be the process for moving images  
          'Like  
          System.IO.File.Copy(Application.StartupPath + "\File\Pic1.jpg", "D:\File\Pic1.jpg")  
      End If  
  End Sub
```

I was tired with that code, is there a shorter coding ?
for example, if the checkbox1.checked = true and another checkbox not checked then only moving one pict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question, you want to copy pictures 1 to 4 if the checkboxes 1 to 4 are checked.
Try this:

```
Dim SourcePath As string = Application.StartupPath + "\File\"

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    CopyFile(CheckBox1, "Pic1.jpg")
    CopyFile(CheckBox2, "Pic2.jpg")
    CopyFile(CheckBox3, "Pic3.jpg")
    CopyFile(CheckBox4, "Pic4.jpg")
End Sub

Private Sub CopyFile(CB As CheckBox, FileName As String)
   If CB.Checked Then 
        System.IO.File.Copy(SourcePath + FileName, "D:\File\" + FileName)
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: maybe, but in my question, if checkbox 1 checked then pic1 move to directory, and if checkbox 1 and checkbox 2 checked then pic1 and pic2 move to directory and so on

Comment: In my answer, each picture file is dependent only on it's corresponding checkbox, meaning that pic1 is copied if checkbox1 is checked, pic2 is copied if checkbox2 is checked (no matter what the other checkboxes status is) and so on.

Comment: Did it solve your problem? if so, please accept the answer. If not, try to explain what is still wrong.